# How to upload an image using JSP -Servlet and EJB 3.0

Tags: image, jsp, servlets, upload

I want to upload an Image using JSP Servlet and ejb 3.0

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=java+file+upload+tutorial

Answer (score 6):

To start, to select a file for upload using JSP you need at least a HTML `<input type="file">` element which will display a file browse field. As stated in the [HTML forms spec](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html) you need to set the request method to `POST` and the request encoding to `multipart/form-data` in the parent `<form>` element.

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Because the aforementioned request encoding isn't by default supported by the Servlet API before [Servlet 3.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html) (which I don't think you're using because EJB 3.0 is part of Java EE 5.0 which in turn contains Servlet 2.5 only), you won't see anything in the request parameter map. The `request.getParameter("file")` would return `null`.

To retrieve the uploaded file and the other request parameters in a servlet, you need to parse the `InputStream` of the `HttpServletRequest` yourself. Fortunately there's a commonly used API which can take the tedious work from your hands: [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload).

```
List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
for (FileItem item : items) {
    if (!item.isFormField()) {
        // <input type="file">
        System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName());
        System.out.println("File name: " + item.getName());
        System.out.println("File size: " + item.getSize());
        System.out.println("File type: " + item.getContentType());
    } else {
        // <input type="text|submit|hidden|password|button">, <select>, <textarea>, <button>
        System.out.println("Field name: " + item.getFieldName());
        System.out.println("Field value: " + item.getString());
    }            
}
```

Basically you just need to get the `InputStream` from the `FileItem` object and write it to any `OutputStream` to your taste using the usual [Java IO](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) way.

```
InputStream content = item.getInputStream();
```

Alternatively you can also write it directly:

```
item.write(new File("/uploads/filename.ext"));
```

At their homepage you can find lot of code examples and important tips&tricks in the [*User Guide*](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) and [*Frequently Asked Questions*](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html) sections. Read them carefully.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sugestions!I will study the Commons Fileload and I will try to implement in my app, then I will be back.
Take care!
George

Comment: +1. I'd add that you need to add in `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to take care of the first line of code, since `parseRequest()` just returns a `List`

Comment: i've implemented your code but it throws FileNotFound Exception