# JSP Uploading and downloading Video

Tags: jsp, video, upload, download

I want to design a website that allows an admin to download and upload video. Can anyone guide me how to do it? Is it same as upload and download image? Any site have example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uploading can be done the same way. You basically just need to end up with an `InputStream` in the server side which you then write to any `OutputStream` you want, e.g. `FileOutputStream` to store it at local disk file system. Downloading is basically also the same way, you only need to change the `Content-Type` header accordingly to represent the correct content type so that the browser knows what to do with it.

Processing the file upload a Servlet can be done easy with help of [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload). [Here's a basic example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827138/how-to-upload-an-image-using-jsp-servlet-and-ejb-3-0/2827390#2827390). Downloading can be done easy with help of a Servlet which obtains the file as `InputStream` and writes it to `OutputStream` of the response the usual Java IO way. [Here's a basic example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).