# JSP File Upload

Tags: html, jsp, image-processing, file-upload, upload

In my jsp page, I need to upload files, images, Word Documents, Excel sheets, Etc. using a single upload option.

After uploading, I want to place them in a folder which has to be created in user's name(If not exists) within root folder.

Also I need to rename the file into some string like username+serial number.

I should be able to give links to these files for displaying them.

I am new to jsp. please help me.

Comment: [try this answer for image upload](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2827390/1041341)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial should help you: http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/file_upload/Sinle_upload.xhtml.shtml